# non-linear mixed models with categorical covariates: obtain parameter estimates by group

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, nlme

After fitting a non-linear mixed model with crossed categorical covariates, how do you write the model equation (with parameter estimates) for each group combination?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data(CO2)
```

Using the `CO2` data set as referenced in [Pinheiro and Bates 2000](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98882):

```
ggplot(CO2, aes(x=conc, y=uptake, group=Plant))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Treatment ~ Type)
```

[image: Four-paneled figure, breaking down by Type and Treatment, plotting uptake against conc]

Fit a model with an Asymptotic regression model with an offset, allowing the `Asym` and `lrc` to vary by `Type` and `Treatment` (but requiring `c0` be constant), according to a model in section 8.2.2 in Pinheiro and Bates.

```
library(nlme)
fm4CO2.nlme <- nlme(uptake ~ SSasympOff(conc, Asym, lrc, c0), data=CO2, 
                    fixed= list(Asym + lrc ~ Type * Treatment, c0 ~ 1),
                    random = Asym + lrc ~ 1,
                    start = c(32.412, 0, 0, 0, -4.5603,0, 0, 0, 49.344))

summary(fm4CO2.nlme)

Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: uptake ~ SSasympOff(conc, Asym, lrc, c0) 
  Data: CO2 
      AIC      BIC   logLik
  388.418 420.0186 -181.209

Random effects:
 Formula: list(Asym ~ 1, lrc ~ 1)
 Level: Plant
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
                 StdDev     Corr  
Asym.(Intercept) 2.34968017 As.(I)
lrc.(Intercept)  0.07960176 -0.92 
Residual         1.79195963       

Fixed effects:  list(Asym + lrc ~ Type * Treatment, c0 ~ 1) 
                                          Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
Asym.(Intercept)                       41.81755  1.562449 64  26.76410  0.0000
Asym.TypeMississippi                  -10.53047  2.208351 64  -4.76848  0.0000
Asym.Treatmentchilled                  -2.96942  2.213205 64  -1.34169  0.1844
Asym.TypeMississippi:Treatmentchilled -10.89926  3.112279 64  -3.50202  0.0008
lrc.(Intercept)                        -4.55726  0.096292 64 -47.32762  0.0000
lrc.TypeMississippi                    -0.10411  0.121685 64  -0.85557  0.3954
lrc.Treatmentchilled                   -0.17124  0.111962 64  -1.52947  0.1311
lrc.TypeMississippi:Treatmentchilled    0.74124  0.221716 64   3.34322  0.0014
c0                                     50.50804  4.364848 64  11.57155  0.000
```

(output truncated)

I know how to plot the modeled data with conditional predicted values (using the plant information "Plant") and marginal  predicted values (ignoring the plant information; "fixed")

```
plot(augPred(fm4CO2.nlme, level=0:1))
```

[image]

And I know how to add onto data frame the marginal predicted values (ignoring the effect of the plant random effect)

```
CO2$predict=predict(fm4CO2.nlme, CO2 , level=0)
```

**Is there an easy way to obtain the parameters for the four model equations for each of the `Type * Treatment` combos?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Thanks the to always-useful `emmeans` package, this is quite straightforward!  For each parameter, make sure the model equation after the `~` matches that of the `fixed` list of the original model fit.

```
library(emmeans)
emmeans(fm4CO2.nlme,  ~ Type * Treatment, param="Asym")
```

> ```
>  Type        Treatment  emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
>  Quebec      nonchilled   41.8 1.48 64     38.9     44.8
>  Mississippi nonchilled   31.3 1.48 64     28.3     34.2
>  Quebec      chilled      38.8 1.49 64     35.9     41.8
>  Mississippi chilled      17.4 1.44 64     14.5     20.3
>
>
> Confidence level used: 0.95
> ```

```
 emmeans(fm4CO2.nlme,  ~ Type * Treatment, param="lrc")
```

> ```
>  Type        Treatment  emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
>  Quebec      nonchilled  -4.56 0.0910 64    -4.74    -4.38
>  Mississippi nonchilled  -4.66 0.1015 64    -4.86    -4.46
>  Quebec      chilled     -4.73 0.0897 64    -4.91    -4.55
>  Mississippi chilled     -4.09 0.1715 64    -4.43    -3.75
>
> Confidence level used: 0.95
> ```

```
emmeans(fm4CO2.nlme,  ~ 1, param="c0")
```

> ```
>  1       emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
>  overall   50.5 4.12 64     42.3     58.7
>
> Confidence level used: 0.95
> ```

Gather these values in a single data frame:

```
Asym_vals <- emmeans(fm4CO2.nlme,  ~ Type * Treatment, param="Asym") %>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  rename_with(.fn=~paste0(., ".Asym"), .cols=emmean:upper.CL)

lrc_vals <- emmeans(fm4CO2.nlme,  ~ Type * Treatment, param="lrc") %>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  rename_with(.fn=~paste0(., ".lrc"), .cols=emmean:upper.CL)

c0_vals <- emmeans(fm4CO2.nlme,  ~ 1, param="c0") %>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  rename_with(.fn=~paste0(., ".c0"), .cols=emmean:upper.CL)


modeleqns <- Asym_vals %>% 
  left_join(lrc_vals, by=c("Type", "Treatment"), suffix=c(".Asym", ".lrc"))%>%
  merge(c0_vals, by=NULL)%>%
  select(Type, Treatment, starts_with("emmean."))
modeleqns
```

> ```
>          Type  Treatment emmean.Asym emmean.lrc emmean.c0 
> 1      Quebec nonchilled    41.81755  -4.557257  50.50804
> 2 Mississippi nonchilled    31.28708  -4.661367  50.50804
> 3      Quebec    chilled    38.84812  -4.728499  50.50804
> 4 Mississippi    chilled    17.41839  -4.091365  50.50804
> ```